# how to deal with DLL function with output parameter as UINT8* and UINT16* in VB

Tags: vb.net

C++ code:

```
BOOL ReadVersion(UINT8 *MajorVersion, UINT8 *MinorVersion1, UINT16 *MinorVersion2, UINT16 *MinorVersion3)
```

we will get out put in *MajorVersion,*MinorVersion1,*MinorVersion2,*MinorVersion3 how to call and get output from vb.net.

VB.net DLL import with func def:

```
<DllImport("eCAMFwSw.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>

Public Shared Function ReadVersion(ByVal MajorVersion() As Byte,
                                               ByVal MinorVersion1() As Byte,
                                               ByVal MinorVersion2() As UInt16,
                                               ByVal MinorVersion3() As UInt16) As Boolean
```

vb.net code:

```
Dim FWVer1(),FWVer2() As Byte

Dim FWVer3(),FWVer4() As UInt16

ReadVersion(FWVer1, FWVer2, FWVer3, FWVer4)
```

am getting error : Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: They are not arrays.  Use ByRef instead of ByVal

Comment: Also you need to specify EntryPoint in DllImport which is in your case "ReadVersion". I never specify the calling convention,I think only FastCall is supported in 64 bit